# What happens if the DC voltage of a positive clipping circuit is put to a negative value?

Tags: diodes, voltage-clipping

[image]

While working with this circuit I observed something which is completely new for me.

The output of this circuit is [image]

It is showing that current is flowing through both the diodes. But how come is that possible? Here the only source that is supplying current is the AC source then how is it possible that in each cycle constant current is flowing through D2 from c to a again a same constant current is flowing through D1 from a to b?
[image]

Comment: Measure the current. Also calculate the power in the diodes. I think you'll find something is wrong with this choice of voltages :)

Comment: potential difference across the terminals of diode is around 1.5V which seems to be wrong somewhere

Comment: If V2 = -5 V and V3 = 2 V, this means that a total voltage of 7 V is applied to the string of two forward-biased diodes (short connection).

Comment: shouldn't that be 3V instead of 7V since their polarity are same so in  series one would decrease the higher  one?